# Конфликт темы приложения и темного режима на телефоне

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Возникла проблема с темами в приложении. Если быть точнее, когда я запускаю свое приложение на устройстве (Xiaomi), приложение удачно работает и приложение оформлено правильно, в соответствии с темой и цветами, которые я задал. Но стоит мне на устройстве выбрать режим: "Темный режим" или ("Режим заката" на других устройствах), как все цвета приложения неестественно искажаются. Какие-то объекты затемняются, как например (Actionbar, Основное Activity). Некоторые наоборот светлеют: текст ListView, Окно WebView. Я к сожалению не могу найти, как исправить эту проблему. Можно ли как-то например отдельно прописать тему для таких режимов? Заранее благодарен за любую помощь!

P.S: `AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_NO);` почему-то не работает в связке с `Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight`.

themes:

```
<resources xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
    <style name="Theme.Slovar" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryVariant">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorOnPrimary">@color/navigationBarColor</item>
        <item name="colorSecondary">@color/colorAccent</item>
        <item name="colorSecondaryVariant">@color/teal_700</item>
        <item name="colorOnSecondary">@color/black</item>
        <item name="android:statusBarColor" tools:targetApi="l">?attr/colorPrimaryVariant</item>
    </style>

    <style name="Theme.Slovar.NoActionBar">
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    </style>

    <style name="Theme.Slovar.AppBarOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />

    <style name="Theme.Slovar.PopupOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />
```

themes (night):

```
<resources xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
    <style name="Theme.Slovar" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryVariant">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorOnPrimary">@color/navigationBarColor</item>
        <item name="colorSecondary">@color/colorAccent</item>
        <item name="colorSecondaryVariant">@color/teal_700</item>
        <item name="colorOnSecondary">@color/black</item>
        <item name="android:statusBarColor" tools:targetApi="l">?attr/colorPrimaryVariant</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

colors:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <color name="colorPrimary">#ECC34B</color>
    <color name="colorPrimaryDark">#E1AA04</color>
    <color name="textColorPrimary">#FFFFFF</color>
    <color name="windowBackground">#FFFFFF</color>
    <color name="navigationBarColor">#000000</color>
    <color name="colorAccent">#B16F0C</color>
    <color name="black">#FF000000</color>
    <color name="white">#FFFFFFFF</color>
</resources>
```

Manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.slovar">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/icon"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden">
        <activity
            android:name="@string/1_name"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.Slovar" />
        <activity
            android:name="@string/2_name" //WebView
            android:theme="@style/Theme.Slovar" />
        <activity
            android:name="@string/3_name"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.Slovar"
            android:label="@string/app_name" />
        <activity
            android:name="@string/5_name"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.Slovar"/>
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity" //Скрытая активность от пользователей. Здесь отдельная тема. 
            android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Translucent">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Искажение цветов происходит на реальном устройстве? Или в АндроидСтудио тоже при переключении на темный режим?

Comment: Искажение происходит именно на устройстве. При переходе на темный режим студии, все хорошо

Comment: Устройство от Xiomi? Если да - то посмотрите тут: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62696305/theme-problem-when-dark-mode-is-activated-under-miui-11-12 . Надо вот такое в стиль добавить: `<item name="android:forceDarkAllowed">false</item>`

Comment: но эта строка запрашивает API уровнем от 29, поэтому AS создал ещё один файл themes.xml (night-v29). Или надо было в светлый стиль добавлять?

Comment: По идее можно в обычный файл стилей добавить. Чтобы не ругалось - укажите в атрибутах вот это: `tools:targetApi="q"`

Answer (score 0):

Подытожив все комментарии, составлю ответ и мое решение. Могу сказать, что строка `AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_NO);` у меня работала по причине как раз отсутствия `<item name="android:statusBarColor" tools:targetApi="l">?attr/colorPrimaryVariant</item>` в моей теме.

1. Для начала надо перевести тему приложения на DayNight. Например, как у меня: `<style name="Theme.Slovar" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.DarkActionBar">`
2. Далее надо прописать в файле themes.xml для своей темы: `<item name="android:statusBarColor" tools:targetApi="l">?attr/colorPrimaryVariant</item>`
3. И заключительным шагом будет являться добавление в свою активность, которая оформлена нашей темой, этой строки: `AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_NO);`, которая принудительно включит светлый режим.

Проблема решилась этими 3-мя шагами. Благодарю всех за вашу помощь!